# Green box appears above/below web components when scrolling

Tags: windows-10, scrolling

I took a slow-mo video of what happens and you can view it here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hiao3IeNFGfVgrPlc3XS7WLYXIWsWj2s/view

In short, when I scroll on my windows 10 x64 PC with Chrome 72, a green box comes out of the opposite way I'm scrolling for a split second and then disappears. It is absolutely driving me nuts.

- This has happened with a completely different hardware config (a laptop) but the same windows 10 image.  This is a desktop PC that I am currently on (GTX 1080)
- This has happened with previous versions of Chrome
- A similar thing happens with IE and Firefox but with different colors and different hide speeds
- Its not limited to one website, it happens on pretty much every website
- I have tried disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome to no avail

Any suggestions as what it could be and potentially how to disable it?  Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a green box. I only see the separator lines turning green during the scroll and an artifact on the screen from the last green line not yet being erased. Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, the green that shows on the tops and bottoms of the boxes.

Comment: I don't think that there is a solution. This relates to the way that Chrome refreshes the screen, and you can't control it. The most you can do is complain on the Chromium forum, but even if some developer decides to do something about it, it will take time.

Comment: Then how come it affects both FF and IE too?  And how come its only this PC/Windows image?  It doesn't affect any of my home PCs or other PC.  If it was a chrome issue, I should have seen this on other PCs at some point

Comment: Different hardware behaves differently.

Comment: Again, this I have seen on multiple PCs here at work, all with different configs.  But I have not seen this *anywhere* else, either at home or previous jobs.

Comment: If some application bothers the refresh mechanism of Chrome, search for it. For example, use Chrome Incognito mode to disable extensions.

Comment: In chrome incognito, its now a dull yellow instead of green, but it still persists.

Comment: Next (and probably last): Boot in Safe Mode With Network to see if this happens when using Chrome Incognito. This will tell you if it's some installed product.